# When using multiple source files, how do you see which one Puppet is going to use?

Tags: puppet

Say you had a file directive like so:

```
***SNIP***
file: "/tmp/file_I_need":
    path => "/tmp/file_I_need",
    ensure => "present",
    source:[
        "puppet://$fileserver/files/$name/file_I_need",
        "puppet://$fileserver/files/$group/file_I_need",
        "puppet://$fileserver/files/default/file_I_need",
        ];
***SNIP***
```

And then each file like so:

```
files/name_that_exists>/file_I_need
files/group_that_exists>/file_I_need
files/default/file_I_need
```

The question is this:

How do I tell which source file puppet is using?
If I am running puppet on different hosts, I expect different files, I know it will use the file that matched first.

Short of modifying the file and seeing if the changes made it,is there a way to see exactly which of the 3 source files it chose?

This is puppet 2.6.2.(Server running on Debian)

> NOTE:
>
> I am seeking a different method than using a hash of the file.
> I also do not like the solution of putting the filename(or similar) somewhere
> in each file.
> I want to know how to get the path from puppet.

Comment: The md5 sum of the file used is reported, it is a bit tedious, but you use that to determine which file was used.

Answer (score 0):

put $hostname to file name or directory name:

```
source => ["puppet://${fileserver}/files/${name}/file_for_${hostname}.txt",
"puppet://${fileserver}/files/${name}/file_for_default_host.txt"]
```

Comment: I am looking for a place where puppet would tell me, I(puppet) used this file : files/node1/file_I_need